# react doesn't render anything on my window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, react-dom

```
{
 "name": "app",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": ".tmp/main/index.js",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "electron ."
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "MIT",
 "devDependencies": {
 "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
 "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
 "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
 "electron": "^1.6.1"
 },
 "dependencies": {
 "firebase": "^5.8.6",
 "photon": "github:connors/photon",
 "react": "^15.4.2",
 "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
 "react-router": "^3.0.0"
 }
}
```

Here is my package.json file

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";

render(<div>Hello. Electron and React JSX</div>,document.getElementById("app"));
```

This is my app.jsx file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron chat</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/photon/dist/css/photon.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="window">
            <div id="app" class="window-content"></div>
        </div>
        <script>require("./.tmp/renderer/app.js")</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my index.html code. I want my jsx file's "Hello. Electron and React JSX" message to be shown on my window,  but only blank page appeared. What should I fix to get better result?

Comment: Have you configurated electron to open your file by default?

Comment: `<script>require("./.tmp/renderer/app.js")</script>` `require` return a value and it should be assigned to a variable

Comment: Your file name is app.jsx and you are importing app.js in index.html file

Comment: sorry for lack explanation. I have .tmp directory transpiled by babel.

Answer (score 0):

You have typos:

Fix in package.json:

```
"main": "./tmp/main/index.js",
```

Fix in index.html:

```
require("./tmp/renderer/app.js")
```